# What exactly do probability generating functions produce at different derivatives at 0 and 1? I feel like different sources say different things

Tags: probability, probability-theory, generating-functions

but more likely I'm just misinterpreting the information.

Say I have a probability generating function for a random variable

$$G_x(s) =\sum_{i = 0}^{\inf}is^i$$

Then plugging in 0 at the rth derivative gets us the probability of the individual rth term right?

Plugging in 1 at $$G_x^{'}(s)$$ gets us the expected value of X right?

and what does plugging in 1 at the rth derivative give us?
I'm not sure if this is all right, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The probability generating function of a random variable $X$ taking values in $\{ 0, 1, 2, \dots \}$ is
$$
G_X(s) = \mathbb{E}[s^X] = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X = x) s^x
.
$$
If you differentiate (assuming we can interchange the expectation/infinite series and differentiation), then formally at least, we have
$$
G_X'(s) = \mathbb{E}[X s^{X-1}] = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x \mathbb{P}(X = x) s^{x-1} ;
$$
subbing in $s = 0$ gives us $G'_X(0) = \mathbb{P}(X = 1)$, and subbing in $s = 1$ gives us $G'_X(1) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x \mathbb{P}(X = x) = \mathbb{E}[X]$.

More generally, for the $r$th derivative, the same reasoning would show that
$$
G_X^{(r)}(s) = \mathbb{E}[X(X-1) \cdots(X-r+1) s^{X-r}] = \sum_{x=r}^{\infty} x(x-1)\cdots(x-r+1) \mathbb{P}(X = x) s^{x-r} .
$$
Subbing in $s = 0$ gives us $G_X^{(r)}(0) = r(r-1) \cdots (2)(1) \mathbb{P}(X = r) = r! \mathbb{P}(X = r)$, or equivalently $\mathbb{P}(X = r) = G_X^{(r)}(0) / r!$. Subbing in $s = 1$ gives us $G_X^{(r)}(1) = \mathbb{E}[X(X-1) \cdots (X - r + 1)]$, which is the $r$th factorial moment of $X$.